# How to calculate max buy and sell amounts of a token?

Tags: forks

There are some contracts on the ethereum blockchain (like [this one](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb7498e5a4cb51fcaf9b6674f35f9abeb85ecea0c)) that has either predefined max buy and sell amounts and/or function for setting max buy and sell percent/amount etc. I am trying to automatically calculate these amounts when I enter the contract address. But I couldn't find any resources for doing this. The best idea I have currently is to fork blockchain at the given block and simulate buying for different amounts to find the upper limit, but from the performance point of view, it doesn't seem feasible. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: This question is too general. Are you asking about the restriction of a specific DEX or specific type of token?

Comment: I will update the question now, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard problem. I think what you did is reasonable (It's what I would do to solve it also). Because there is no standard for this max_amount and it's up to each contract to implement their own.

```
    uint256 private _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(2).div(100);
```

There are 3 approaches that I can think of:

1. Checking storage slot is only applicable to this single contract, this wont guarantee that other contracts will use the same storage slot or the same check to implement max amount. **(Not accurate)**
2. Analyzing code of `_transfer`. Because there is no guarantee that the contract that you want to check has source code. The analysis should be done on bytecode. Basically, I will try to check if any comparison happens to the `amount` parameter using some bytecode disassembly. Writing this solution automatically and accurately is quite difficult. **(Low accuracy and hard to implement)**
3. Binary search the amount on mainnet fork. This is feasible with the complexity is O(log2(N)) with upper bound is the `totalSupply` and lower bound is `0`. E.g. when the token supply is `2^64`, you only need maximum 64-65 iterations to find it. [Read more about binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). **(Accurate & easy to implement)**

Personally, I would try `2.` and `3.`  The approach `3.` is more pragmatic and always give you the correct result. While 2 may be faster but may give wrong result.

Comment: thanks for your thorough response, seems like the 3rd one is the only choice I have. How much time do you think would be needed for doing that 64 iterations?

Comment: I dont use mainnet fork on hardhat or truffle a lot but I think just a few seconds. If you have your own eth node for that purpose alone, it could be under a sec. If the mainnetfork use 3rd party service like infura, they may have limit on their API (e.g. 10 calls/sec)